# Refactor packages of a jar

Tags: java, refactoring, jar

I am having some troubles with a jar, and I want to rename all clases to avoid conflicts, but I only have the final jar :(

Classes in jar are in package as it:

org.foundation  and I want to be available in another jar as

org.foundation.oldversion

Is there any tool to do it ?

I don't want to decompile.

Comment: How about naming your new packages org.foundation.newversion? :)

Comment: just curious, why do you need such thing?

Comment: We have some packages with no version and same classes name in same project, some times a class is loaded with errors (when someone change path classes) then I want to avoid it, but no decompile :), and @Paul nooo I just need the oooold old version, changing name is not a reason for give it a new version number :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/)

> You can avoid problems where your library depends on a specific version of a library, which may conflict with the dependencies of another library.

Comment: I am going to try it, but the project is not working with ant, this can be a good moment.... :) thanks